# PHP Create Zip destination to a folder not on root

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

I have a code to create a zip of a folder but the zip file goes to the root i want to create the zip in a folder like "zips" or something else not in the root... This is the code.

```
//Create Zip
function create_zip($files=Null,$destination = '',$overwrite = false) {
//if the zip file already exists and overwrite is false, return false
if(file_exists($destination) && !$overwrite) { return false; }
//vars
$valid_files = array();
//if files were passed in...
if(is_array($files)) {
    //cycle through each file
    foreach($files as $file) {
        //make sure the file exists
        if(file_exists($file)) {
            $valid_files[] = $file;
        }
    }
}
//if we have good files...
if(count($valid_files)) {
    //create the archive
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if($zip->open($destination,$overwrite ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE : ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true) {
        return false;
    }
    //add the files
    foreach($valid_files as $file) {
        $new_filename = substr($file,strrpos($file,'/') + 1);
$zip->addFile($file,$new_filename);
    }
    //debug
    //echo 'The zip archive contains ',$zip->numFiles,' files with a status of ',$zip->status;

    //close the zip -- done!
    $zip->close();

    //check to make sure the file exists
    return file_exists($destination);
}
else
{
    return false;
}
}

//zip

        $error = "";        //error holder

            $file_folder = "uploads/tracks/";   // folder to load files
            if(extension_loaded('zip')){    // Checking ZIP extension is available
                    $zip = new ZipArchive();            // Load zip library 
                    $zip_name = time().".zip";          // Zip name
                    if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE){       // Opening zip file to load files
                        $error .=  "* Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time<br/>";
                    }
                    foreach($post['files'] as $file){               
                        $new_filename = substr($file,strrpos($file,'/') + 1);
 $zip->addFile($file,$new_filename);        // Adding files into zip
                    }
                    $zip->close();
                    if(file_exists($zip_name)){
                        // push to download the zip
                        header('Content-type: application/zip');
                        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$zip_name.'"');
                        readfile($zip_name);
                        // remove zip file is exists in temp path
                        unlink($zip_name);
                    }
            }else
                $error .= "* You dont have ZIP extension<br/>";

    }
}
```

All i want is to send the zip files to a folder not the root.

Answer (score 0):

function create_zip($files=Null,$destination = '',$overwrite = false)
Here at $destination give your location or folder name where you want to store the file.

Comment: function create_zip($files=Null,$destination = 'root/anypath/filename.php' ,$overwrite = false)
did you tried like this?

Comment: i dont know what is wrong, i have hours trying to make it work and nothing yet